# Error with glmnet? Says I have NA but I removed those?

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am trying to run this code:

```
set.seed(216)
cvmod.0 <- cv.glmnet(y=DATA5$armedornot, 
                    x=as.matrix(DATA5[,-1]), 
      alpha=0.25, family= "binomial", 
      type.measure = "class")
```

but then I get this:

> Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs, : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this! I removed the NA values, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: It's not really saying there are NA's or Inf values in your data. You need to offer the results of debugging efforts since the error was not immediately present when the interpreter evaluated the arguments to cv.glmnet. We don't really know without looking at the data path for `y` inside glmnet whether the the `y` that was passed to lognet was the same `y`. You may have tried to take the log of 0 for instance, since that would have produced an `Inf` result.